# Android: Can't download vitamio SDK

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I need to support the m3u8 live video so I tried to download the vitamio SDK but their website is down.
Is there anywhere else I can download the SDK or can someone please email it to me?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can download it from here https://dl.dropbox.com/s/9s65mxj67ix4t3d/Vitamio-SDK.7z?dl=1

Comment: Please download from http://vitamio.org or https://github.com/yixia

Comment: it was down for some reason, now it seems to work again.